# What's the best way to check if an active record object has just been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Specifically I want to check that the record has been created in the database, but there haven't been any subsequent updates.

Up until now I've been checking that the `updated_at` and `created_at` are the same, but I've found that depending on the amount of work required to create the model, these can sometimes differ by a few milliseconds.

Right now I'm using `if self.changed? && self.id_changed?`, as the only time the `id` will change will be when the object is first saved. This works fine, but I'm curious to see if there's a more well established way of doing this.

Comment: Use `obj.new_record?` method to see if the object is a new record

Comment: But `new_record?` is only true if the model hasn't been saved yet. What I'm looking for is to know that the model has been created (i.e. saved to the database), but hasn't had any subsequent updates.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Please update your question for clarity. Also consider replacing every instance instance of `model` in your question with `object`.

Comment: Thanks. The persisted? method is just used to show that it's saved to the database, so is true after creation and also true after all updates.

Comment: @ArunKumar Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question.

Comment: `created_at` and `updated_at` shouldn't differ at all, unless you use some after_save/after_create hooks which do another save. In which case, the record _did_ receive a subsequent update.

Comment: `.changed?` is from activerecord::dirty module. It doesn't work as you may think it does.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, Sergio? The reason I'm checking `.changed?` is to ensure that something changed on the object in general, before checking what happened.

Comment: If you change something on an existing record and then save it, `.changed?` will return false after the save. It only indicates presence of unsaved changes.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Thanks. For the record, this is being called in an `after_save`, not sure if that has any impact?